Trying to find hillbilly drama movie from 60's to 70's
Hi trying to find a 60's to 70's movie about a Charlton Heston type character who is held hostage on a farm by hill billy kids! The main actor is a city journalist of some sort, who is going for a drive in the country to clear his mind. 
He is led to the farm after he gets lost and picks up the youngest kid of the family near a field. The protagonist drives a white car, possibly a Cadillac. Eventually he decides to go to the kid's run down farm after a rough drive in the backwoods. A storm picks up and the kid claims that the river they crossed earlier is too dangerous to go cross. He takes shelter in their run down farm house.
The main actor meets the rest of the family, two girls and two other boys (three boys in total). The oldest boy is in charge and claims their parents have gone to town to sell their hogs. After some questioning, this gets proven to be false and the oldest admits he shot the parents and the journalist is now held hostage. He meets the family nanny who is also held hostage.
The kids want him and the nanny to replace their own parents. The actor complies but eventually makes an escape attempt. Don't remember too much else, except his car gets driven into the rivet as a punishment and a scene where he is trying to outrun the kids (again) near a river. The main reason I'm trying to find the movie is it has a good psychedelic rock song around this scene that I'm trying to find.

Took a while but I managed to find it. 
It's All the kind strangers ( IMDb, Wikipedia)
IMDb description*

A couple traveling through a backwoods area are held by a a group of orphans who want them to become their parents. Unfortunately, the kids have a habit of killing adults who refuse that particular honor.

Below is the trailer:




Self answer is fine, no need to delete but it's better to give a descriptive answer. Anyway remember to select you own answer as accepted by clicking the check button.
